# how to use instr in informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a requirement where the column name invc_amt_type  whihc ahas data as  mail serive count, mail service amount,other count, other amount and so on.
 i also have a amount  coulmn coming form source invc_amt whihc has amounts in it.
 now i need to put a logic in expression as(some thing like compare)  check if the invc_amt_type has value as'COUNT'  then load the invc_amt in column A , if invc_amt_type has 'AMOUNT' then load the invc_amt in column A.
 i tried using insrt and look for word 'COUNT' and load the inv_amt in column A (instr(INVC_AMT_TYPE,'COUNT')>0) but iam little confused how to use for 'AMOUNT'.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Kiran,
 You can use **IIF** function,

```
IIF(INSRT(INVC_AMT_TYPE,'COUNT') 
OR INSTR(INVC_AMT_TYPE,'AMOUNT'),INVC_AMOUNT)
```

This logic will help you

Comment: Kiran but one thing, you are loading amount into A column for both the conditions. If you could provide your data, will be helpful to solve your problem